# How to show/hide a nebular action item after signed in?

Tags: angular, nebular

I managed to create menu items with Angular Nebular theme
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/actions/overview#nbactionscomponent

And understand i could show/hide the menu items using *ngIf

```
<nb-actions size="small">
  <nb-action icon="nb-search"></nb-action>
  <nb-action icon="nb-power-circled"></nb-action>
  <nb-action icon="nb-person" *ngIf="(BOOLEAN VARIABLE)"></nb-action>
</nb-actions>
```

But my challenge now, the code above under app.component.html. What if i need to show/hide after user login via login component, how could the app.component 'listen' to the 'signed in' signal and show/hide the actions accordingly?

Comment: You can use a flag or localstorage and set it true/false

Comment: Thanks! @Beller! it just work like magic!!